# Windows Forms. Как сменить ip?

Tags: winforms

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос: 
Есть форма, на которой помещён контрол webbrowser, загружающий определённый сайт. На нём происходят рассылки. После первой рассылки, чтобы отправить вторую, нужно ввести капчу. Я заметил то, что если я сменяю ip и обновляю страницу, то капча исчезает.

Хотелось бы поместить на форму ещё одну кнопку, при нажатии на которую менялся бы ip. Вопрос: как сделать такую кнопку?

Comment: А как вы его меняли вручную, каким способом?

Comment: Через SwitchySharp Options. Это расширение для гугл хрома.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или у вас есть динамический IP от провайдера и тогда берёте программку для перезагрузки своего роутера, или пишите свою по логам любого сниффера.
Или берёте список прокси серверов и делаете рассылку по нему, при первом варианте много времени тратится на рестарт роутера, при втором нужно периодически обновлять таблицу прокси серверов, т.к. они часто мрут.

Comment: не могли бы вы описать второй вариант?

Comment: Могу, точнее формулируйте вопрос... По поиску в любом поисковике, "свежие прокси" можно найти список, есть программки для их проверки, чтобы отсеить мёртвые или медленные